# Search a string in multiple files using Perl

Tags: file, perl, search, grep

Newbie to Perl!! need some help :)
I have 2 files of size nearly 500kb each.

And i need to search a set of strings (approx 800 strings) in these files to check if the string in present in file 1, file 2 or in both or neither of them.

The only option that i am aware of is to open file1, read line by line and check is the string is present in it and do the same with file2. 
Doing the entire process for nearly 800 strings (search strings) dont seem to be good nor effective.

Is there any other alternative which is more efficient or a single line code for it using PERL ?

Comment: With small files like that you can use [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) to read them into a single string and look for your 800 words in that all in one go; search 800 times each file instead of 800 times each line in each file.

Comment: How big are the files? And, are the 800 strings plain old strings, or are they regular expressions?  Finally, within the files, must the strings be found verbatim, or could there be differences in whitespace such as newlines?

Comment: The two files are roughly 500kb each and the all strings that are to be searched are plain strings of length 12. When we search these strings in those files, they should make an exact match and there wont be any whitespaces between them.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to mention that while searching for the strings, i also need to note down the line number in which the strings were found. So in case if I use the File::Slurper method as mentioned above, will i be able to get the line number ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using [`Regexp::Assemble`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble). Assuming the strings to be matched does not span multiple lines, it creates a common regex for all the strings that can be checked for each line. Hence, it only needs to read the files once.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Assemble;

my @strings = qw(abc efg);  # <- Add more strings here

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
$ra->add( $_ ) for @strings;  # <- Creates a regexp that matches all the strings..
my $re = $ra->re;
my @files = qw(file1.txt file2.txt);  # <- Add more files if needed..
my @matches;
for my $file (@files) {
    push @matches, get_matches( $file, $re );
}
# Now post process the matches as you like..

sub get_matches {
    my ( $fn, $re ) = @_;

    my %matches;
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        while ( $line =~ /($re)/g ) {
            $matches{$1}++;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
    return \%matches;
}
```